# Convert to 3 decimal while retain as number format for calculation purpose

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have an issues where i can't retain 3 decimals places if i convert fields to numeric, as i need to have 3 decimal places and the cell format to be numeric for calculation purposes
i am using this formula

```
=FIXED(VALUE(IF(J7="PAJ",Q7,"0")),3)
```

For 1st formula, yes i can convert it to 3 decimal places but i can't do any calculations.
Sample data outcome for 1st formula:
0.000
1.664
1.714

if i am using this formula

```
=Value(Fixed(IF(J6="PAJ",Q6,"0"),3))
```

For 2nd formula, i can convert it to numeric format and perform calculations, but i can't make it 3 decimal places.
Sample data outcome for 2nd formula:
0
1.75
1.763

Comment: Three decimal places is just a *display* issue; do it with cell formatting, not in your calculations.

Comment: You are totally right, that's just a display issue, just did it, issues solved. Thank you man